# URL Rewriting on multiples folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I need to Rewrite my URL :

I got two folders : `folder1/file.php` and I need just "file" in address bar
                  : `folder2/file.php` and I need just "file2" in address bar 
And I got other files in root

When I use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder1)
RewriteRule (.*) /folder1/$1 [L]
```

It's working but if I access to `file2`, I can't because it's searching on `folder1/file2.php` and it's not found!

If I try to access to `index.php` it's searching on `folder1/index.php`

I know how to remove file extensions but I can't find how to rewrite correctly my folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to set up conditions to check if the files exist in folders too:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder1/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder2/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder2/$1 [L]
```

This requires that your filenames are unique in both directories and would fail if they both have `somefile.php` in them.

Comment: ... I tried this but with %{REQUEST_URI}, thanks a lot !